# Current Date and Current time in hidden fields

Tags: forms, date, time, field, hidden

Hi I am looking for a way to add 2 hidden fields in my form that hold the current date and current time.

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="CurrentTime"> 
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="CurrentDate">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Downvoting as combining a couple of *insert favourite search engine* results would throw up the answer to this one. Clearly no research effort has been done, and simply posting some HTML isn't "showing code that you've already tried"...

Comment: I do not know how you got the information about what I have already done. I have been searsing for 2 days, tried like a hunderd diffrent things and codes. Should I paste all the things I tried? I do not know if this will help, it will become a very large and messy post.

Comment: Sorry to come across a little harsh, @user2765741. I've posted an answer below. The way to achieve what you're after, is using JavaScript. Essentially, the searches you need to perform were "get current date in javascript" and "get current time in javascript". Hope my answer can help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using JavaScript.

Include some `id`s in your `input` elements, so you can identify them in JS:

```
<input type="hidden" id="date" name="date" value="CurrentTime"> 
<input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="CurrentDate">
```

You can then use JS's `Date()` function to get the current Date. Create a variable as a `new Date()`, then use the methods on that variable to get the parts of the date and time you're after!

Here's the script you'll need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();

    // Set the value of the "date" field
    document.getElementById("date").value = d.toDateString();

    // Set the value of the "time" field
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("time").value = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + seconds;
</script>
```

Here's a JSFiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/y3go8hm8/ -
*note, I've changed the `type` to `text`, rather than `hidden` - or you wouldn't be able to see it working!)*

---

**Formatting**

You can format the date however you like, so my example above gives you the date as "Mon 12 Jun 2010" format.

Let's say you want `dd/MM/yyyy` format:

```
// Get today's date
var day = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // The months are 0-based
var year = d.getFullYear();

// Set the date field to the current date
document.getElementById("date").value = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Caveat of this is, that months or days less than 10 will only display to 1 digit (e.g. 12/3/2014). Likewise, this applies for the `time`, too.

You can loop through the day and month and prepend `0`, if you wish;

```
if (day < 10) {
  day = "0" + day;
}
if (month < 10) {
  month = "0" + month;
}
```

and do the same for the `hours` and `mins` of the time:

```
if (hours < 10) {
  hours = "0" + hours;
}
if (mins < 10) {
  mins = "0" + mins;
}
```

And *then* assign the values to the fields, as above.

Here's a JSFiddle of this in action, too: https://jsfiddle.net/y3go8hm8/1/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi this helped so much, my main issue was with the things I tried was viewing the page source to see the if the hidden field worked and of course it just showed "CurrentDate" so I thought it was not working.

I ended up making the script like this:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mhmvtbn/)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @user2765741. Glad to have helped you out. Don't forget to upvote useful answers, and mark as answer (when you can) :) **TIP:** For future posts, I would advise that you post things that you have tried and results, rather than just posting some HTML -it can be very unclear what you've already tried, hence getting a bad rap for it. Try and be as thorough as you can without being verbose. Happy coding! :)